# Enums have no overlapp

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export enum DocumentStatesA {
  signed = "signed",
  shared = "shared",
  sent = "sent",
  refused = "refused",
  canceled = "canceled",
}
export enum DocumentStatesB {
  SIGNED = "signed",
  SHARED = "shared",
  SENT = "sent",
  REFUSED = "refused",
  CANCELED = "canceled"
}


let c:boolean = DocumentStatesA.signed === DocumentStatesB.SIGNED
```

I have the problem that my framework generates me two enums, one is with `signed` and one is with uppercase `SIGNED`, now when i want to check them it says:

> This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types
> 'DocumentStatesA' and 'DocumentStatesB' have no overlap.(2367)

How can i do a check without throwing this error?

Comment: `let c: boolean = DocumentStatesA.signed.toUpperCase() === DocumentStatesB.SIGNED.toUpperCase();`

Comment: Enums are intentionally prevented from being mixed like this; ideally you would not use enums for this purpose, but you can always widen one or both of them to `string` before comparing, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4QGBw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?